# How to prevent race conditions when user information changes during the time a request goes from a client to a server?

Tags: web, client-server, race-condition

I want to build a web application that relies on names, instead of hard-to-remember IDs, to access information about users. For example, `GET /@user1`, would return the profile of `user1`.

However, I still want my users to be able to change their username. AFAICT this means I need to translate it to a unique ID at some point, and then use it to perform operations.

For example,

```
GET  /@user1/id         => Returns 123, the ID associated to user1
POST /user/123/message  => Sends a message to the user with ID 123 (which should be user1)
```

My question is how can I prevent two users from changing usernames between the first and second request, which could result in the wrong data being accessed?

To illustrate this better, imagine a client wants to display the profile of `user1`, identified by the number 123:

- the client clicks on their profile link and makes a request to `/@user1`;
- while the request is in transit, `user1` changes their username to `user2`;
- while the request is still in transit, `user2`, identified by the number 456, changes their username to `user1`;
- the server receives and handles the request by sending back the information of `user1`, which is the profile that corresponds to ID 456, instead of 123.

Is there a better way to design such an application? Or security/integrity checks I can implement to detect this behavior and fail/retry the request?

I doubt I'm the only one who faced this problem, but after spending some time searching for different solutions to TOCTOU/race conditions affecting client-server architecture, I haven't been able to find a proper answer. Hopefully someone can give me a definitive answer or at least point me in the right direction to find it.